# app does not function properly in iphone 5 and 4s simulator

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, ios-simulator, uiviewanimation

This is the weirdest thing, when I run my app in any simulator on xcode it functions normally except when I try to run it in the iphone 4s simulator and the iphone 5 simulator it acts funny. So in the function below is where I have the animations taking place. And what I mean by acting funny is that normally these animations run smoothly and you can see the dots that I created move across the screen gradually but in the iphone 4s and 5 simulators you dont see the animations at all or you see just very brief flashes of them I have no idea why. Please help!!

func go () {

```
    // Remove add banner from view
    self.gameAdBanner?.hidden = true


    // Enable the user interaction of the content view
    self.contentView.userInteractionEnabled = true

    // Make the level label appear
    UIView.animateWithDuration(0, delay: 1, options: nil, animations: {
        self.levelLabel.alpha = 1
        self.levelNumber.alpha = 1
        }, completion: {finished in self.displayAd()})


    // Declare delay counter varriables
    var delayCounter:Int = 100000
    var durationCounter:Double = 0




    // Initiate the starting level
    levelNumber.text = String(level)




    // Set up random number varriable that will make the amount of dots in each color very from one color to another
    var diversifyRedDots = arc4random_uniform(5)
    var diversifyBlueDots = arc4random_uniform(5)
    var diversifyYellowDots = arc4random_uniform(5)
    var diversifyGreenDots = arc4random_uniform(5)


    // Create if statement for first 2 levels so dots always spawn
    if level < 3 {

        diversifyRedDots = 4

    }







    // LOOP------------------

    for loop in 0...loopNumber {



        // set up some constants for the animations

        let redDelay = NSTimeInterval(arc4random_uniform(100000) + delayCounter) / 30000

        let blueDelay = NSTimeInterval(arc4random_uniform(100000) + delayCounter) / 30000

        let yellowDelay = NSTimeInterval(arc4random_uniform(100000) + delayCounter) / 30000

        let greenDelay = NSTimeInterval(arc4random_uniform(100000) + delayCounter) / 30000



        let options = UIViewAnimationOptions.AllowUserInteraction | UIViewAnimationOptions.LayoutSubviews



        //set up some constants for the dots

        let redSize:CGFloat = 54

        let redYPosition : CGFloat = CGFloat( arc4random_uniform(150)) + 54



        let blueSize:CGFloat = 54

        let blueYPosition : CGFloat = CGFloat( arc4random_uniform(150)) + 54



        let yellowSize:CGFloat = 54

        let yellowYPosition : CGFloat = CGFloat( arc4random_uniform(150)) + 54



        let greenSize:CGFloat = 54

        let greenYPosition : CGFloat = CGFloat( arc4random_uniform(150)) + 54



        // create the dots and add them to the view
        let redDot = UIButton()

        redDot.setBackgroundImage(RedDot, forState: UIControlState.Normal)

        redDot.frame = CGRectMake(-100, redYPosition, redSize, redSize)

        self.contentView.addSubview(redDot)



        let blueDot = UIButton()

        blueDot.setBackgroundImage(BlueDot, forState: UIControlState.Normal)

        blueDot.frame = CGRectMake(-100, blueYPosition, blueSize, blueSize)

        self.contentView.addSubview(blueDot)



        let yellowDot = UIButton()

        yellowDot.setBackgroundImage(YellowDot, forState: UIControlState.Normal)

        yellowDot.frame = CGRectMake(-100, yellowYPosition, yellowSize, yellowSize)

        self.contentView.addSubview(yellowDot)



        let greenDot = UIButton()

        greenDot.setBackgroundImage(GreenDot, forState: UIControlState.Normal)

        greenDot.frame = CGRectMake(-100, greenYPosition, greenSize, greenSize)

        self.contentView.addSubview(greenDot)







        // DEFINE THE ANIMATIONS
        // Red

        if diversifyRedDots > 5 {

            // Increase actual red
            self.increaseRed()

            // Increase count dot number


            UIView.animateWithDuration(dotDuration , delay: redDelay - 6, options: options, animations: {

                redDot.frame = CGRectMake(700, redYPosition, redSize, redSize)

                }, completion: {finished in redDot.removeFromSuperview()})

        }





        // Blue

        if diversifyBlueDots > 5 {

            // Increase actual blue
            self.increaseBlue()

            // Increase count dot number

            UIView.animateWithDuration(dotDuration , delay: blueDelay - 6, options: options, animations: {

                blueDot.frame = CGRectMake(700, blueYPosition, blueSize, blueSize)

                }, completion: {finished in blueDot.removeFromSuperview()})

        }



        // Yellow

        if diversifyYellowDots > 5 {

            // Increase actual yellow
            self.increaseYellow()

            // Increase count dot number

            UIView.animateWithDuration(dotDuration , delay: yellowDelay - 6, options: options, animations: {

                yellowDot.frame = CGRectMake(700, yellowYPosition, yellowSize, yellowSize)

                }, completion: {finished in yellowDot.removeFromSuperview()})

        }




       // Green

        if diversifyGreenDots > 5 {

            // Increae acutual green
            self.increaseGreen()

            // Increase count dot number

            UIView.animateWithDuration(dotDuration , delay: greenDelay - 6, options: options, animations: {

                greenDot.frame = CGRectMake(700, greenYPosition, greenSize, greenSize)

                }, completion: {finished in greenDot.removeFromSuperview()})


        }














        // Incremint counters

        delayCounter+=50000

        diversifyRedDots++
        diversifyBlueDots++
        diversifyYellowDots++
        diversifyGreenDots++



    }
```

Comment: Why do you have massive amounts of blank lines between code?

Comment: idk lol its easier for me to read, can you help me man?

Comment: I removed un-related code (gameBanner, level number, just keep the code for handling colored-buttons) and with loopNumber = 10, all things go well with both iPhone 5 and 4s.

Comment: interesting, so what do think is causing something like this?

Comment: figured it out it was something because of the load function